# python click event scope issue in pygame

Tags: python, scope, mouseevent, pygame

I've created a GameObject class, using the python pygame library, which draws a rectangle on the screen.
   I would like to integrate an event handler which would allow me to draw the rectangle around, however the click events for the GameObject are not registering. 
Here are a couple snippets of code from the class:

`def on_event(self, event):`

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print "I'm a mousedown event!"
        self.down = True
        self.prev_x=pygame.mouse.get_pos(0)
        self.prev_y=pygame.mouse.get_pos(1)

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
        self.down = False
```

`def on_draw(self, surface):`

```
    #paints the rectangle the particular color of the square
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, pygame.Color(self.red, self.green, self.blue), self.geom)`
```

Do I need to make the rect into an image for the mouse events to register, or is there some other way I can drag this box around?

Comment: 'click events not registering' - as in, your on_event method is never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Do I need to make the rect into an image for the mouse events to register, or is there some other way I can drag this box around?

No image required. Solution:

Note:

1. You already use event to get MOUSEMOTION, so use event's data: .pos, and .button from the event.
2. use [Color](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) class to store as a single variable:

   self.color_bg = Color("blue")
   self.color_fg = Color(20,20,20)
   print self.color_bg.r, self.color_bg.g, self.color_bg.b

Note: I kept some code slightly more verbose to make it easier to read, ex: you could do:

```
# it uses
x,y = event.pos
if b.rect.collidepoint( (x,y) ):
# you could do (the same thing)
if b.rect.collidepoint( event.pos* ):
```

Solution:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

class Box(object):
    """simple box, draws rect and Color"""
    def __init__(self, rect, color):
        self.rect = rect
        self.color = color
    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)

    class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # random loc and size boxes
        # target = box to move
        self.target = None

        for i in range(5):
            x,y = randint(0, self.width), randint(0, self.height)
            size = randint(20, 200)

            r = Rect(0,0,0,0)
            # used 0 because: will be using propery, but have to create it first
            r.size = (size, size)
            r.center = (x, y)
            self.boxes.append( Box(r, Color("red") ))

    def draw(self):
        for b in self.boxes: b.draw()

    def on_event(self, event):
        # see: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button = 1:
            # LMB down = target if collide
            x,y = event.pos
            for b in self.boxes:
                if b.rect.collidepoint( (x,y) ): self.target = b

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button = 1:
            # LMB up : untarget
            self.target = None

        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            x,y = event.pos
            # is a valid Box selected?
            if self.target is not None:
                self.target.rect.center = (x,y)
```